# connecting DocumentDirect using vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to connect excel to an applicaiton named `DocumentDirect`. Its a desktop application.
Can we connect `VBA` to applicaions like `DocumentDirect` for extracting data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "connect"?

Comment: Would help to provide a link to some information about your application: a google search turns up multiple possible matches...

Comment: @Mat'sMug actually I want to refer or target to the nodes of the treeview control of this Application (DocDirect). From my little knowledge (being a beginner) I understand that we would need a library to be added in the references of the VBA code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish, what you've got, what you're expecting, and what's not working. From your comment it seems you'll have to do some Win32 API calls to do that - that's not for the faint of heart, and not quite beginner-level either.